# returning specific values extracted from an hstore (Postgres + hstore_translate gem)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, rails-i18n, hstore

I am using [hstore_translate](https://github.com/Leadformance/hstore_translate) within a Rails4 project to handle
my I18n needs.

Assume I have the following model:

```
class Thingy < ActiveRecord::Base
  translates :name
end
```

with table defined in a migration as

```
create_table :thingies do |t|
  t.hstore name_translations
end
add_index ::thingies, :name_translations, using: :gin
```

In my Ruby code I wish to retrieve a list of the all the `names` and `ids` for `Thingies` with a name in a specific `locale`.

Previously, before my `Thingy` had a localised `name`, I could just do

```
thingies = Thingy.order(:name).pluck(:id, :name)
```

Now I am doing

```
thingies = Thingy.where("name_translations ? 'en'").order("name_translations -> 'en'").to_a.map do |t|
  {id: t.id, name: t.name}
end
```

But I can't help feeling there's a way I can better leverage Postgres to do this all in one line of code without invoking a loop in Ruby.

Comment: Have you tried `Thingy.order("name_translations -> '#{params[:locale]}')` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've worked it out with a bit of trial and error.

```
thingies = Thingy.where("name_translations ? 'en'")
                 .order("name_translations -> 'en'")
                 .pluck(:id, ("name_translations -> 'en'"))
```

does the job.

It's not very DRY but it works.